# Which of these covariate options is most appropriate?

Tags: regression, predictor

I'm looking at the exam results of a university course. The exam was completed by 500 people, who each completed 105 multiple choice questions. I have each person's total score on the exam (*ExamTotalScore*).

11 of those questions were on a topic that was quite unrelated to the other questions within the course, and I can separate out scores on that part of the exam (*ExamTopic1Score*). The mean *ExamTopic1Score* is 7.5, SD 2.4, range 0 to 11.

Students were required to complete 54 training questions on Topic 1 prior to the exam. I can see their score out of 54 (*Topic1TrainingScore*).

I'm interested to assess the efficacy of the training materials for Topic 1. Since it's impractical for me to do that in an experimental way, I was thinking of constructing a simple model in which *Topic1TrainingScore* predicts *ExamTopic1Score*.

One objection to that model is that people who are skilled at exams are  generally conscientious and would tend to do better on the training materials even if they were useless. As some measure of control for that I thought of including a covariate.

Which of these covariates is more appropriate, and why?

1. Use *ExamTotalScore* as a covariate.
2. Make a new variable *ExamNonTopic1TotalScore* and use that as covariate. That is, *ExamTotalScore* after scores on the Topic1 questions have been subtracted out.
3. Use something else as a covariate.
4. Don't use a covariate.

My initial inclination was with '2', since otherwise the outcome variable *ExamTopic1Score* and the covariate *ExamTotalScore* are very linked, in that an extra point for a student on *ExamTopic1Score* automatically means an extra point *ExamTotalScore*. However, I'm not sure how to explain why this is a problem.

Also, I would welcome general impressions on whether my approach is appropriate.